# Do I need `propTypes`?

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

I am practicing [Redux Saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga-beginner-tutorial)
With [Tutorial Repo](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga-beginner-tutorial)

I had tried comment out the lines

```
Counter.propTypes = {
  value: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  onIncrement: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onDecrement: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

It seems no impact to the application.

**Question**:
Is it safe to ignore them?
And what is the best practice?

```
/*eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'

const Counter = ({ value, onIncrement, onDecrement, onIncrementAsync }) =>
      <div>
        <button onClick={onIncrementAsync}>
          Increment after 1 second
        </button>
        {' '}
        <button onClick={onIncrement}>
          Increment
        </button>
        {' '}
        <button onClick={onDecrement}>
          Decrement
        </button>
        <hr />
        <div>
          Clicked: {value} times
        </div>
      </div>

Counter.propTypes = {
  value: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  onIncrement: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onDecrement: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default Counter
```

Comment: Its not a must one. Its a nice to have feature. The official docs tells you what it does. https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html If you are convinced by their logic to use them, use it.

Comment: @Panther Oh. Sorry. I was searching for `saga`.